# Random image looping in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to loop random images from a folder. So far, I can loop the images but everytime I try to use random.choice, I'm getting an error. Below is my code without random imported

```
import tkinter as tk
import glob
root = tk.Tk()
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root.geometry('600x600')

pics = glob.glob("./imgs/*.png")
photos = [random.choice(tk.PhotoImage(file=x)) for x in pics]
label = tk.Label(root)
label.photos = photos
label.counter = 0
def changeimage():
    label['image'] = label.photos[label.counter%len(label.photos)]
    label.after(8000, changeimage)
    label.counter += 1
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
changeimage()
root.mainloop()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ad/Documents/Python/Project_tkinter/test1.py", line 148, in <module>
    photos = [random.choice(tk.PhotoImage(file=x)) for x in pics]
  File "/Users/ad/Documents/Python/Project_tkinter/test1.py", line 148, in <listcomp>
    photos = [random.choice(tk.PhotoImage(file=x)) for x in pics]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'PhotoImage' has no len()
```

Comment: it would help us if you could provide the traceback

Comment: Hey, not sure what you mean by traceback. I've updated the code so you can run it yourself. Just replace the folder path to your own path.

Comment: you say you're getting an error, what do you mean by that?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see `random.choice` in your code. Show code which makes problem.

Comment: `traceback` means FULL error message - starting at line with word `Traceback`. People often show only last line of error message or try to describe error, or (the worst) they only write "I get error" - and this is useless.

Comment: your error shows problem with `random.choice` then show code with `random.choice` too. Working code without `random.choice` is useless.

Comment: Just updated the code. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: you have to first create list of photos and later use `random.choice(list_of_images)`. In current code you use single image -  `random.choice(single_mages)` - but `choice()` needs list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first create list of photos and later choose single photo

```
list_of_photos = [tk.PhotoImage(file=x) for x in pics]
single_photo = random.choice(list_of_photos)
```

but if you want to loop this list then you rather need `random.shuffle()` to change order on the list to have files in random order.

```
list_of_photos = [tk.PhotoImage(file=x) for x in pics]
random.shuffle(list_of_photos)
```

`random.shuffle()` changes original list and it doesn't return new list.

Comment: Ah works! thank you!
What you said makes sense. In my other project I used random.choice for a string list and it worked. I thought it would work the same way for images in a folder as well. Thanks for the clarification. Learned something new :)